# What does the overloads of InvokeAsync method do in Razor pages

Tags: c#, blazor

About these:

```cs
Task InvokeAsync(Action workItem);
Task InvokeAsync(Function< Task> workItem);
```

Description:

> Executes the supplied work item on the associated renderer's
> synchronization context.

But what does that actually stands for? What are the use cases of those functions?
Is there any more in-depth documentation to look up about this feature? I had exceptions thrown in my projects requesting the usage of those methods in specific circumstances but never had any really understanding of what's happening there

Comment: Every time i search about it, i only get the definition of InvokeAsync from ViewPages which i strongly believe is not the same thing

Comment: It executes the code on the UI thread. Use this if you are changing UI, such as `StateHasChanged()` which will update the UI to reflect the current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blazor Virtual DOM is single-threaded and not thread-safe.
Like any other UI framework.

So when you are on a code-path that might execute on a different thread you have to use InvokeAsync() to delegate any UI operations to the sync context. The most common pattern looks like:

```
private void TimerCallBack()   // might run on a pool thread
{
   // execute some logic, update the state

   // request execution of StateHasChanged() on the UI thread
   InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);  
}
```

For the moment only Blazor Server(-interactive) can use multiple threads. But let's be prepared for the day Blazor Wasm gets threads too and always follow this pattern.

In the 'normal' Blazor events line OnInitialized, OnParametersSet and OnClick you are always running on the right thread already.
But from any other trigger, or when in doubt, use InvokeAsync().

Comment: the returned Task from the InvokeAsync runs in parallel here doens't it? I mean, since you dont await it

Comment: Yes, somewhat in parallel. Use `await` when possible but in a timer event you can't and then this is acceptable. Make it the very last line in the callback.

Answer (score 1):

In server hosted Blazor where multiple threads are used, they allow you to run code, such as `StateHasChanged()` that can interact with components, in their own thread via the synchronization context. Without them, there would be threading issues caused by threads fighting to modify the same components.

When threading is finally available in Blazor WASM they may be used there as well.

[ASP.NET Core Blazor synchronization context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/synchronization-context?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

> Blazor uses a synchronization context (SynchronizationContext) to enforce a single logical thread of execution. A component's lifecycle methods and event callbacks raised by Blazor are executed on the synchronization context.

Example use:

```cs
    public async Task OnNotify(string key, int value)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(() =>
        {
            lastNotification = (key, value);
            StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
```

The above method OnNotify method can be called by any thread, which then uses InvokeAsync to call the lambda method on the synchronization context thread to modify the components data and then call StateHasChanged() to tell the component to re-render.

Without InvokeAsync the above code would throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

> Original removed as @HH has already provided an answer.

`ExecuteAsync` is implemented in `ComponentBase` as follows.

```cs
 protected Task InvokeAsync(Action workItem)
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);

    protected Task InvokeAsync(Func<Task> workItem)
        => _renderHandle.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(workItem);
```

`_renderHandle` is a `struct` object passed to the component when the Renderer calls `Attach` on the component.  `Dispatcher` is a reference to the UI `SyncronisationContext`'s dispatcher.